# GAE error using appcfg after a failure

Tags: google-app-engine

```
D:\kubox\python\GAE>appcfg.py rollback D:\kubox\python\GAE\myapp1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\kubox\python\GAE\appcfg.py", line 77, in <module>
    DIR_PATH = get_dir_path(os.path.join('lib', 'ipaddr'))
  File "D:\kubox\python\GAE\appcfg.py", line 67, in get_dir_path
    'file and %s.' % sibling)
ValueError: Could not determine directory that contains both, this file and lib\
ipaddr.
```

After a failure deployment, I can't perform the appcfg.py, did I make a wrong syntax?
where did I do wrong?
WIN 7, cmd prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running appcfg.py from where your GAE SDK is installed.

Comment: surely I did it, or the output will be "it's not a commond or bat file"

Comment: If your GAE SDK is in D:\kubox\python\GAE, D:\kubox\python\GAE\myapp1 isn't the best place to put your app.  You probably don't want to change anything in D:\kubox\python\GAE.  I'm not sure that this is the problem though.  In any case, you're getting an error message because somehow D:\kubox\python\GAE\lib\ipaddr cannot be found.

Comment: oh,thanks,I don't have a "ipaddr" folder in the GAE\lib folder, is that a install problem? I will reinstall it later and give you a reply then

Answer (score 0):

Usually rollback should suffice, but after a failure in deployment, sometimes the upload doesn't work by default.

As a work around, you can change the app version (app.yaml), and then try deployment, It should go fine.

Next you can log in to your applications dashboard and in versions tab, you can switch the latest version as default one. Your new version should be up and running now.
  As a last step you can stop any instances of old version of your app.

Hope this helps